# Simplifying $\frac{2\sinh^2 x}{(\cosh x+1)^3}-\frac{\cosh x}{(\cosh x+1)^2}$

Tags: trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

Could you explain me how we simplified this trigonometric expression?

> $$\frac{2\sinh^2 x}{(\cosh x+1)^3}-\frac{\cosh x}{(\cosh x+1)^2}\qquad\to\qquad\frac{\cosh x -2}{(\cosh x +1)^2}$$

Thanks.

Comment: $2\sinh^2x=2\cosh^2x-2$, so putting over a common denominator, the numerator becomes $\cosh^2x-\cosh x-2$ which factorises.

Comment: @almagest, it sounds like you have an answer. Why not post it as such?